# MYSQL join taking too long to execute

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a simple join on two tables which is taking around 50 secs to execute and Im not too sure why?

heres the code:

```
    SELECT

  LEFT(t1.group, 3) AS `Group`,
  max(t1.`Z-indexnummer`) As 'ZI-Nummer',
  count(t1.`Z-indexnummer`) As 'PacksDispensed',
  t2. `Artikelomschrijving: inkoophoeveelheid (aantal)`as 'Packsize',
  t2.`Prijs: apotheekinkoop (ex. BTW)` As 'Prijs EX BTW',
  Afleverapotheek, Zorgverzekeraar, Basisproduct, Etiketnaam,
  t2.`Gm.: productnaam: PRK=prescriptie (code)`, t2.`Naam: productverantwoordelijke`,
  t2.`Inkoopkanaal (code)`,
  t3.mnvddd
FROM My_Data as t1
INNER JOIN ZINummer as t2 ON t1.`Z-indexnummer` = t2.`Artikelnummer: ZI-nummer`
INNER JOIN Idea as t3 ON t1.`Z-indexnummer` = t3.atkode
WHERE 

t1.`VPV-Weekaflevering` = '0, Gewone Levering'

  group by t1.`Z-indexnummer`
  order by PacksDispensed desc;
```

Has anyone any ideas? help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give some additional information e.g., how big are the tables, are there any indexes on the tables, can you show the query execution plan?

Comment: Its happening due to mysql functions that you have used on query i.e. LEFT(), max() and count().

Comment: Thanks Amiya, is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: 'If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate,' Nothing to do with performance but is that really what you want?